# Which platforms have limited buffer sizes?

Tags: java, groovy

The Groovy [Process Management](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management) page mentions that:

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input
>   and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output
>   stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock

This snippet comes from the JDK API. Which platforms, in particular, are these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also happens on Linux and (I expect) Solaris.

In fact, I would be surprised to find *any* conventional OS platform that provides unlimited buffering for process-to-process streams; i.e. pipes in UNIX terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I know this happens on Windows at least.  This is why a child's stdin and stdout must be read in another thread.